# MySQL REGEXP to match zeros in comma separated list

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table column that consists of a short comma separated list of integers.

I am trying to build a query for reporting purposes that identifies the number of rows that contain the following:

- list has leading zero
- list conatains zeros
- list is all zeros

Below is what I have so far (I could only figure out leading zero):

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN col REGEXP '^0.*' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as leadingZeros,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN col REGEXP '....' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as containsZeros,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN col REGEXP '....' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as allZeros
FROM table;
```

I am looking for regular expressions to fit the 2nd and 3rd case.

Note: this column will contain only integers, never decimals/floats.

Comment: Ambiguous.  Does "123,3004,555" contain zeros?  Does "012" contain leading zeros, or only "0,0,123"?  When asking about "zero" do you mean the "number" (as in `0`, but not `01` nor `101` nor `110`)?  Or the "digit" (all of those contain 'zero')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> list contains zeros

Since you are looking for a whole word match, use

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]]0+[[:>:]]'
```

The pattern matches:

- `[[:<:]]` - leading word boundary
- `0+` - 1 or more `0`s
- `[[:>:]]` - trailing word boundary

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jR8bY9/1) (PCRE equivalent used just for demo purposes)

> list is all zeros

You need anchors `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string):

```
REGEXP '^0+(,0+)*$'
```

`+` means 1 or more occurrences.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU0mU4/1), explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `0+` - 1 or more `0`s
- `(,0+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `0+` - one or more `0`s
- `$` - end of string

Comment: would that not give a false positive in a list like `12,134,102`? where it matches the zero in `102`?

Comment: Aha, you mean a *whole* word match? Use `REGEXP '[[:<:]]0[[:>:]]'` then

Comment: and does your all zeros solution account for commas? I thought something like that would match `0` , `00` , `000` , etc.

Comment: all zeros solution makes sense, do you mind explaining the syntax in the contains zeroes solution?

Comment: I have added all explanations and demos.

Comment: these work perfectly and make sense once I looked into regexp word boundaries. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

2. `,0+,|^0+,|,0+$`

   - 3 alternatives for zeroes at beginning, middle, and end.
3. `^(0,?)+$`

   - `^` and `$` are anchors
   - `(0,?)+` means multiple zeroes that may be followed by a comma.

Comment: I selected the other answer due to more comprehensive explanations/demos plus a cleaner solution to case 2. However I am using your solution for case 3. Thank you!

Comment: Compare the number of steps [`^0+(,0+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/oD0dF8/1) takes - 12 - to match the input, and [`^(0,?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/oD0dF8/2) - 83. Regexes are better when they match *linearly*. Shorter patterns do not have to be more efficient.